# Spring Data Pagination returns wrong number of content as it is requested

Tags: java, spring, pagination, spring-data-jpa

currently I am developing an api which uses `Spring Data Pagination` and I came to the problem that I passing a `Pageable` object as a request to my repository with which page I want to receive and how many elements should be on it. And with that my object looks like: `Pageable pageable = PageRequest.of(0, 2);` - so I want first page with two elements. In my database are 3 objects so therefore there will be 2 pages. But what ide shows me is: [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/75V1h.jpg). Can anyone tell me why it shows that content is an array of 3 elements but actually I asked for 2 elements?

```
   @Override
public List<NotificationDto> getLast30NotificationsFor(ApplicationUser user) {
    Pageable pageable = PageRequest.of(0, 2);
    Page<Notification> first30ByOwnerIdOrderByCreatedAtDesc = notificationRepository.findFirst30ByOwnerIdOrderByCreatedAtDesc(user.getId(), pageable);

    List<Notification> notifications = new ArrayList<>(first30ByOwnerIdOrderByCreatedAtDesc.getContent());
    return notifications.stream()
            .map(NotificationToDtoMapper::map)
            .collect(toList());
}
```

Comment: and size is 2 is pageable request...as you see in screenshot I asked for 2, not for 3...

Comment: Your pageable is useless. Your query method is converter into a query and it will always select the first 30. Hence the limit you give in your pageable is not taken into account.

Comment: @M.Deinum why it is useless?

Comment: Because in your query you always select 30.

Comment: @M.Deinum but why?

Comment: @M.Deinum where in the above code is that?

Comment: As stated the method is translated into a query. YOur method starts with `findFirst30By` which is the signaal to always return the top 30 results regardless. So your page size is always 30. Your ordening is also in the query method so not sure what you think to actieve by passing in a `Pageable` into this method.

Comment: @M.Deinum ah ok, so it indicates JPA to get 30 records even though there are only 3 records in dB?

Comment: It will get max 30 records, regardless of how many records there are and how maby you want from your pageable.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
@Override
public List<NotificationDto> getLast30NotificationsFor(ApplicationUser user) {
    Pageable page = PageRequest.of(0,2, Sort.by("createdAt").descending());
    return notificationRepository.findByOwnerId(user.getId(), page)
    .getContent()
    .stream()
    .map(NotificationToDtoMapper::map)
    .collect(toList());
}
```